# Enable right click with two finger tap?

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

I have a Lenovo Ideapad s145. I cannot find any option to enable right click by two finger tap on touch pad.

I have gone through the usual procedure to enable right click by two finger tap on touch pad. But I could not find any option to enable it.

The procedure to enable right click by two fingers tap is

**Windows 10**

Windows start Menu>Settings>Devices>Touchpad>Check Two finger Tap

But in my case, there is no check box to enable right by two finger tap gesture.

[image: But there is no such option in my case.]

**Is there any thing which I can do?**

**What have I tried?**

[How to enable right click with two finger tap](https://mywindowshub.com/how-to-enable-right-click-with-two-finger-tap-gesture-on-windows-10/)

**Details**

```
Laptop: Lenovo Ideapad s145
OS: Windows 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the touchpad drivers, which usually come with a utility that allows you to customize the touchpad behavior (right-click, scrolling, etc.). It should look something like this:

[image: Synaptics touchpad utility]

Assuming that you're using a 64-bit version of Windows 10, you may download the drivers from [this link](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles/6yst09af09mc.exe).

If you want to download the drivers for a different version of Windows, you may go to [this page](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-s-series-netbooks/s145-15iwl/downloads/automatic-driver-update) for automatic driver update.